# How to add a space between every int and non-int value?

Tags: java

I would like to add a space between every number and non-number in a string, and also between each non-number.

For example:
"133+23d-="   ➟ "133 + 23 d - ="

Here is my attempt:

```
for(int i=0; i<input.length();i++){
    if((Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1))) || (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1))) || (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1)))){
        input = input.substring(0, i) + " " + input.substring(i, input.length());
    }   
}
```

(where "input" is the string I want to do this to)

Currently the loop just loops infinity for some reason??

Comment: use split function to break your string down based on Char, add spaces and concatenate your output string.

Comment: because you are adding more character to a string you are currently looping.

Comment: @JustLearning I don't know if the split function would help since it will consume the separator character

Comment: increment `i` in the `if` to skip the test on the new space added. This should do it

Comment: if you split by `+` then you will get: `133` and `23d-=` in your first array, you can then split the second array again to achieve similar effect.

Comment: If you were to insert a space between every int and non-int, wouldn't the output be `133 + 23 d-=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reassigning `input` in the loop and extending its length, while also using the length as a condition to terminate on. So you will also take the newly added whitespace into account, which will trigger yet another whitespace to be inserted, etc.

Instead of directly modifying the `input`, you should store the result in a separate variable (ideally a `StringBuilder`, for performance reasons).

Also, since your `i` is running from `0` to `length-1`, you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to access `charAt(i+1)` in the last iteration of that loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to detect the positions before and after a non-digit character `\\D`.

```
String input = "133+23d-=";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\D)|(?=\\D)", " ");
// '133 + 23 d - = '
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/hzgjPb)

Comment: @4castle is there a way I could add a space after a "-" only if it isn't before a number. Such as "12-12" ➟"12 -12" and "23-d"➟"23 - d".

Comment: Well, that seems like a separate question, but you could remove the space after using my answer by doing `output.replaceAll("-\\s+(\\d)", "-$1")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.

```
String s = "133+23d-=";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "$1 "); //finds every consecutive digits and puts a space after them
s = s.replaceAll("([-a-zA-Z]+)", "$1 "); //finds every consecutive characters and puts a space after them
```

Comment: I was about to put the same code, using only "([+-*/=])" for the regex ;) `ìnput.replaceAll("([+-*/=])", "$1 ");`

Comment: What does "(\d+)" and "$1 " mean?

Comment: (\d+) means any number of consecutive digits. $1 means "content of first ()"

Comment: `$1` mean everything that match the part between `( )`, `\d` is for any digits and `\w` is for every character. @cokceken, add your explanation in your answer ;)

Comment: You have to insert two escape characters. `"(\\d+)"` and `"(\\w+)"`

Comment: When using \d, I get the error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: @Alfie put two backslashes as I explained

Comment: Also the `replaceAll()` does not modify the current string, the result of the replacement is returned by the method so you have to store it in a variable

Comment: oh, sorry I didn't notice that

Comment: How would i go about inserting a space between every non int value, such as "11 asd" into "11 a s d"?

Comment: Well the `\w` matches the digits too so you should use a character class instead in the second replace: `s = s.replaceAll("([-a-zA-Z=+*/])", "$1 ");`

Comment: You can learn and try regex from here: https://regex101.com/ and the answer is s.replaceAll("(\\w)", "$1 ") because "+" means 1 or more characters

Comment: @cokceken is there a way I could add a space after a "-" only if it isn't before a number. Such as "12-12" ➟"12 -12" and "23-d"➟"23 - d". Thanks, I really appreciate this. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add a space between every number and non-number in a
>   string.
>
> For example: "133+23d-=" ➟ "133 + 23 d - ="

As you described the problem, I think the result should be "133 + 23 d-=" .

Basically this should be the algorithm

```
        String input = "133+23d-=";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean number = false;
        for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ){
            if( input.charAt(i) < '0' || input.charAt(i) > '9' ){ // not a digit
                if( number ){
                    result.append(" ");
                }
                number = false;
            }else{
                if( !number ){
                    result.append(" ");
                }
                number = true;
            }
            result.append(input.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you insert one position before. Let's do it by hand:

- i=0 : process 1 and 3 - both digits nothing is changed
- i=1 : process 3 and 3 - both digits nothing is changed
- i=2 : process 3 and + - digit and no digit => add a space at position **i**! `input` becomes wrongly `13 3+23d-=`. So you will continuously add spaces before the last 3 and get an infiny loop.

But that's not all, even if you fix it with:

```
input = input.substring(0, i+1) + " " + input.substring(i+1, input.length());
```

and get correctly `133 +2d-=` things will still break:

- i=3: process  (space) and `+` => both are not digits and you still add a space.

Here again you get an infinite loop adding spaces before the `+`.

*Hell is hidden in details*! After adding a space, you must skip it, and you must stop one position before last because you later use `input.charAt(i+1)`.

Your fixed code becomes:

```
    for (int i=0; i<input.length() - 1; i++) {
        if ((Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1))) || (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1))) || (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1)))) {
            input = input.substring(0, i+1) + " " + input.substring(i+1, input.length());
            i += 1;
        }
    }
```

TL/DR: all that would have been self evident if you had simply run the loop under a debugger. Eclipse of Netbeans both include a nice one.

But that's not all. You are repeatedly re-assigning the input String. Even if low case optimizations should be avoided in early development stages, this is *bad*. It would be cleaner to browse the input string, adding original chars and spaces into a StringBuilder and only at the end extract the resulting String from the StringBuilder.